# SQL Oracle Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm using Oracle SQL developer, i get good resuls, but when i'm using oracle BI it gives me the following ORACLE error: ORA-00905: Missing keyword.

MY guess is that problem is with :

```
from table1 c1 left join (select x, y from table2 group by x, y) b1 ON c1.x= b1.x
```

when i change it

```
from table1 c1 left join table2 b1 ON c1.x= b1.x
```

it gives me no error and wrong results.

How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Please share your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with what you posted is that the subquery has a group by clause but no aggregate such as sum(), count(), etc.  In other words, this is not valid:

```
select x, y 
from table2 
 group by x, y
```

Maybe you want

```
select distinct x, y 
from table2
```